# How to express counter type entity with UML?

Tags: uml, modeling

I would need some help with a problem we're facing in a company, trying to model every process and entity.

So far we have used an enhanced conceptual model with entities and attributes with relationships but there are some objects that don't exactly match a dimension or a fact table, and this is an entity that can be called "**Shops with sales over X units**". There is the entity "**sales**" and "**shop**" obviously, that would have it's representation in UML as independent entities and represent at the lower level, each sale and shop.
What we need to indicate in UML is an entity that stores the counter of shops with sales over X units, so this has some kind of behavior or conditions.
If we consider the entity, it would need date-from and date-to, and the value (counter), and creating a connection with the shop entity seems enough, but we miss the behavior that expresses "more than x sales". So the behavior could be for example: Go to the shop entity, take the 1st element and navigate to the sales entity, calculating the sales. If it's over X, then value+1, and so on.

I made a simple version of the problem. Blue boxes represent the entities already created, and the orange one is the counter that should count the shops with some constraints.

[image: Diagram example]

Is there any way of using some kind of UML diagram that can help us to solve this problem?

Comment: Hu. How about using paragraphs to structure your question (and running a spell checker)?

Comment: It might help to add a little diagram of the parts of the diagram you currently have / are sure of (sales, shop,...), then we can easily react on/enhance your starting model

Answer (score 0):

You could realize that with an association class:

[image]

`ShopSales` relates `Shop` and `Sales` so you can store the number of sales along with other things you might need in that conjunction. The `ShopSalesStats` could give you the shops by number of sales.

Another (of many) way(s) would be to just hold the count as public property of `Shop` and let `ShopSalesStates` handle the counts on all associated `Shop`s.

Comment: First off, thanks for the suggestion. For my understanding, this is an associative class that exists along with the relationship between Sales and Shop, so we could mix info from both entities and from here, create what we need. But what happens if between Sales and Shop there is another entity? For example: Sales --> Entity1--> Shop?
Both are not directly related, is there a way of applying the same solution in this scenario?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What would be Entity1?